# For loop doesn't work well

Tags: java, for-loop, runtime-error

```
package learning;
import java.util.* ;

public class Learning {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String normal , cipher;
        String shiftstr;
        int shiftint, s;

        System.out.println("Welcome To Ceasar Shift Creator");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        normal = in.nextLine();
        char[] proc = normal.toCharArray();
        int length;
        length = normal.length();
        System.out.println("Ok now tell me how many times you want it to be shifted ");
        shiftstr = in.nextLine();
        shiftint = Integer.parseInt(shiftstr);

        s = 0;
        for(int i =0; i < length ; i++){
            while( s < shiftint){
                proc[i]++;
                s++;
            }
            System.out.print(proc[i]);
        }
    }
```

I wanted the whole word to be shifted forward the same no. of times as the user mentions. But only the first letter is shifted. I know I haven't done it quite correctly but still help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner while loop is only entered once, when `i` is 0. That's why only proc[0] is changed.

You don't need the inner loop:

```
    for(int i =0; i < length ; i++){
      proc[i]+=shiftint;
      System.out.print(proc[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

s need to be set back to 0 in the for-Loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        while (s < shiftint) {
            proc[i]++;
            s++;
        }
        System.out.print(proc[i]);
        s=0;
    }
```